# Iterate in the source directory and create zip files using the each child directory: Maven or ant-task

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-ant-tasks

I want to scan 'Test' directory and as per the number of directories in that directory,need to create multiple zip files . 'mydir' folders can repeat so the zip files.  The structure of my project  as follows .

```
+ src
  + main
    + Test
      + mydir
         +version
            +conf
              +a.propeties
            +lib
               +test.jar
            +routes
               +test.routes
        + mydir2
            +version
               +conf
                 +a.propeties
               +lib
                 +test.jar
               +routes
                 +test.routes

  ....................
```

The name of 'mydir' and 'vesrion' can change but under version the directory structure gonna be the same.

I heard of maven iterator plugin ...or should I use maven mojo plugin and write a java class to create multiple zip files?

Comment: this is a perversion of the use of maven and is going to be complicated to do, it would be much better to use maven as it was intended to be used with proper releases and multi-modules

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you need such thing? In particular the jar files look strange?

Comment: I really need to create multiple zip files . I heard of maven iterator plugin ...or should I use maven mojo plugin and write a java class to create multiple zip files?